# TSQL - Loop, Sum rows by conditions

Tags: t-sql

I would be grateful for help in some case. I have data like below:

Table and Data Insert for help

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TestOptions](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Crt_Day] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Lc_Day] [int] NOT NULL,
    [IsActive] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [Weight] [int] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

INSERT INTO [dbo].[TestOptions](Crt_Day, Lc_Day, IsActive, [Weight]) VALUES(1,5,0,50);
INSERT INTO [dbo].[TestOptions](Crt_Day, Lc_Day, IsActive, [Weight]) VALUES(3,6,0,10);
INSERT INTO [dbo].[TestOptions](Crt_Day, Lc_Day, IsActive, [Weight]) VALUES(5,10,0,45);
INSERT INTO [dbo].[TestOptions](Crt_Day, Lc_Day, IsActive, [Weight]) VALUES(6,14,0,7);
INSERT INTO [dbo].[TestOptions](Crt_Day, Lc_Day, IsActive, [Weight]) VALUES(10,12,0,42);
INSERT INTO [dbo].[TestOptions](Crt_Day, Lc_Day, IsActive, [Weight]) VALUES(12,13,1,40);
INSERT INTO [dbo].[TestOptions](Crt_Day, Lc_Day, IsActive, [Weight]) VALUES(14,19,1,11);
```

And my question is how to get by CTE/cursor or other way result like below. I want a sum weight for each distinct day from crt_Day. But this value should include value from other rows based on conditions:

1. include row weight if other row Crt_Day < this.Crt_Day and Lc_Day < this.Crt_Day
2. If row IsActive dont check Lc_Day, this  row weight shoul be included

My final result with I expect  + my coments

```
Crt_Day     SumWeightForDay   

  1              50                f1st row was added
  3              60                50+10 2nd row was added , 1st has Lc_Day later
  5              55                10+45  ( 50 is to remove because of Lc_Day <=5 )
  6              52                7+45   we lost 10
  10             49                7+42    we lost 45
  12             47                7+40     we lost 42
  14             51                11+40   we lost 7 but 40 is Active so we dont check Lc_Day
```

for better understending my code in C# which does exactly what it expects:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        class Detail
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public int CrtDay { get; set; }
            public int LcDay { get; set; }
            public bool IsActive { get; set; }
            public int Weight { get; set; }
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var list = new List<Detail>
            {
                new Detail{Id =1, CrtDay = 1, LcDay = 5,IsActive = false, Weight = 50},
                new Detail{Id =2, CrtDay = 3, LcDay = 6,IsActive = false, Weight = 10},
                new Detail{Id =3, CrtDay = 5, LcDay = 10,IsActive = false, Weight = 45},
                new Detail{Id =4, CrtDay = 6, LcDay = 14,IsActive = false, Weight = 7},
                new Detail{Id =5, CrtDay = 10, LcDay = 12,IsActive = false, Weight = 42},
                new Detail{Id =6, CrtDay = 12, LcDay = 13,IsActive = true, Weight = 40},
                new Detail{Id =7, CrtDay = 14, LcDay = 19,IsActive = true, Weight = 11}
            };

            var days = list.Select(x => x.CrtDay).ToList();

            foreach (var day in days)
            {
                 var weight = list
                    .Where(x => (x.CrtDay <= day && x.LcDay > day && !x.IsActive)
                    || (x.CrtDay <= day && x.IsActive))
                    .Sum(x => x.Weight);

                  Console.WriteLine($"{day} {weight}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The sample output and the C# example doesn't agree with the rules as described - condition 1 should be something like: "include row weight if other row Crt_Day < this.Crt_Day and Lc_Day > this.Crt_Day"

Answer (score 0):

This appears to give the right output. An aggregate query is used to support cases where more than one previous row matches the join conditions:

```
SELECT t1.Crt_Day, SUM(t1.Weight + ISNULL(t2.Weight,0)) SumWeightForDay
FROM dbo.TestOptions AS t1
LEFT
JOIN dbo.TestOptions AS t2
ON  t2.Crt_Day < t1.Crt_Day
AND (t2.Lc_Day > t1.Crt_Day
     OR t2.IsActive = 1
    )
GROUP BY t1.Crt_Day
```